# Dynamic IF condition check

Tags: batch, stateful

I have a requirement to check in an IF condition the various State names and then add each of the records in separate maps with respect to the state names. So each map will have the records of that particular State name.
How do I do that dynamically such that even if new State name is added, it will automatically add it to a new map rather than doing changes in the Code and adding If conditions for all States.

Comment: problem is not clear. can you put some supporting code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without any specific matches in an If-statement. Just have a map that maps state names to maps with your records.
Assuming you want Accounts in your mapped maps:

```
List<Account> myAccounts = [SELECT Id, my_state__c .... FROM Account WHERE ... ];
Map<String, Map<Id, Account>> stateMap = new Map<String, Map<Id, Account>>();
for(Account myAccount : myAccounts) {
    String stateName = myAccount.my_state__c;
    Map<Id, Account> accMap = stateMap.get(stateName);
    if(accMap == null) {
        accMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        stateMap.put(stateName, accMap);
    }
    accMap.put(myAccount.Id, myAccount);
}
```

... of course your query will look different. However, no state name will be hardcoded and you end up with maps containing Accounts neatly separated by state name.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer does answer your question, it would be great if you marked it as accepted answer.